# unable to login in ibm cloud from cli

Tags: authentication, passwords, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, cloud-object-storage

```
Authenticating...

Credentials were rejected. 

Code: BXNIM0602E, message: The credentials you entered for the user '<email>' are incorrect.
```

I have verified my credentials while typing it, however `ibmcloud login` is not accepting the password.

I have referred and tried this link: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-ts_logintoibm

Unable to resolve this issue

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved, my login was from a federated account:

Followed this guide for it: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-federated_id&interface=cli

Answer (score 2):

Seems that this is caused by MFA Setting, even if MFA is not enabled:

In the IBM Cloud Console, select Manage --> Access (IAM) --> Settings --> Authentication.  In my case, in the MFA Panel, the radio button 'None' was selected and the associated checkbox 'Disable CLI logins with only a password' was checked. Unchecking this resolved this issue for me, allowing username / password login with the CLI.

Quite unintuitive that an MFA configuration disables password based login.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the IBM cloud through the web, what you can do is:

1. click on your profile
2. click 'Login to CLI and API'
3. copy the command in the IBM Cloud CLI
4. Paste it in your terminal

This Worked for me